# Is it possible to create multiple navigation drawer activities in android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am developing an android application in which I have created two buttons (Button1 and Button2).On click of Button1, a navigation drawer activity will open. I am succeed in doing all so. But I want that whenever the user clicks on Button2 another navigation drawer activity with different menu items in it will be shown up. Is it possible to create multiple navigation drawer activities in android?
Every kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2016/03/simple-example-of-navigation-view-on.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a NavigationView , you can create two menu , one for Button1 an other for Button2. Then you use `NavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.the_relevant_menu)` when you click on the buttons to change the content of navigation view programmatically.

Hope this helps.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create multiple in different activity but you can create only two navigation in a activity.

Add

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/home_content"></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:layout="@layout/nav_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/nav_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```